# Lion server DNS problem with .private

Tags: dns, server.app

I have just installed a lion server on my home network. I want to use it as a .private. Domain. I have implemented the VPN connection for external users via port fwd on my apple time machine router. The time machine provides dhcp services for e network and my dns severs are set to Comcast dns.

When I try and access the server using the .private domain name the server cannot be found. The server does show up in finder.

My question is this.

What do I need in terms of Dns. Should I point the router to the sever and what records would I need in the server dns config and how would I get DNA requests passed out to the main network for everything els.

Best regards

Mark.

Answer (score 1):

OK for those with the same problem here is the solution I used.

I set the router to use the lion server as the primary DNS and also used the secondary DNS as my ISP DNS.  and it worked.

For the VPN connection I added the lion server as the DNS also but to date I don't have it working perfectly over VPN.